# Debug or disable sendmail auth=SERVER

Tags: authentication, spam-prevention, sendmail

It seems like people are sending spam through my mailserver using SMTP server authentication.

- I’m getting bounces of undelivered mail
- The bounces contain correct Received: headers from my mail server
- My mail server is not an open relay
- I changed the passwords for all accounts on the server

Sample headers of the original mail:

```
Received: from mydomain.net ([190.236.249.21])
    (authenticated bits=0)
    by mymailserver.net with ESMTP id tA9FuD9m015519
    for <xyz@xyzhotmail.com>; Mon, 9 Nov 2015 16:56:34 +0100
```

The IP is not mine, in fact it’s from Peru, and the same kinds of mails are submitted from IPs in India, Malaysia, etc.

The corresponding entry in the mail.log:

```
Nov  9 16:56:17 mymailserver sm-mta[15519]: AUTH=server, relay=[190.236.249.21], authid=my@email.net, mech=PLAIN, bits=0
Nov  9 16:56:20 mymailserver sm-mta[15519]: tA9FuD9h015519: from=<my@email.net>, size=428, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<F67043B1-F959-41D2-F87F-1493F6905FCF@mydomain.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=[190.236.249.21]
Nov  9 16:56:20 mymailserver sm-mta[15519]: tA9FuD9h015519: Milter insert (0): header: Received-SPF: pass (mymailserver.net: authenticated connection) receiver=mymailserver.net; client-ip=190.236.249.21; helo=mydomain.net; envelope-from=my@email.net; x-software=spfmilter 0.97 http://www.acme.com/software/spfmilter/ with libspf-unknown;
Nov  9 16:56:23 mymailserver sm-mta[15519]: tA9FuD9i015519: from=<my@email.net>, size=451, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<53E69BF1-310E-4814-BF49-311956EF726D@mydomain.net>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=[190.236.249.21]
Nov  9 16:56:23 mymailserver sm-mta[15519]: tA9FuD9i015519: Milter insert (0): header: Received-SPF: pass (mymailserver.net: authenticated connection) receiver=mymailserver.net; client-ip=190.236.249.21; helo=mydomain.net; envelope-from=my@email.net; x-software=spfmilter 0.97 http://www.acme.com/software/spfmilter/ with libspf-unknown;
```

I’m stumped – I’m not sure how they get a) `AUTH=server` and b) `authid=my@email.net`. But I’m not sure how to debug this, and I can’t find anything on Google on disabling this kind of authentication, everything only refers to authenticating clients (which is what I do) and identifying towards other servers when sendmail is a client (which I don’t do).

Comment: any solution to this? I am having the same issue...

Comment: Yeah, ancient credentials were cached in some file related to SASL iirc. Unfortunately it’s been a while and I don’t have that server anymore, so I can’t find the details now :( Try running a grep on your /etc/mail (or whatever) for the authid listed in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not generalize, but when tearing down that server a little later, we found a PHP shell that had been dropped through a WordPress bug. All it had been used for was to add a user for mail relaying into the sasl database, as far as we could tell. So, if you also have a similar issue, definitely check for rootkits and droppers, and if you have the slightest doubt that somebody could have gotten access to your server, *nuke it and rebuild it*.